# Are Automatic Ids generated on GCP Google Datastore unique across namespaces for same entity kind

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

There is a kind in my data store that is common across namespaces. I am creating entities in the namespaces with same kind, and using automatically generated ids.

> Datastore mode can also automatically assign IDs. Datastore mode
> generates a random sequence of unused IDs that are approximately
> uniformly distributed.

Does the datastore itself ensure that the same ids are not used across namespaces.
That is, no two entities in two different namespaces should have same ids.
For Example: If I have kind 'Person' in two namespaces, the Person entities in these two namespaces should always be given unique ids.

I have checked this similar question but still not very clear
[Google Cloud Datastore unique autogenerated ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407626/google-cloud-datastore-unique-autogenerated-ids)

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) also mentions:

> Datastore mode will never assign the same numeric ID to two entities
> with the same parent, or to two root entities (those without a
> parent).
> and
> System-allocated ID values are guaranteed unique to the entity group.

So, this does not mention clearly on the namespace part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for Datastore to guarantee that it is allocating unique IDs across all entity groups and namespaces, this is something that although unlikey, may still happen.

Nevertheless, you can generate a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) yourself based in a random seed, and then implement a way to review if the ID is not yet used before assigning it to ensure that there is no repetition through your IDs.

Comment: do you happen to know of any documentation reference clarifying this 'not allocating unique IDs across all namespaces.' that should be helpful.Thanks.